# Make button for positive or negative numbers

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make  button once user clicks by typing +1 or -1 numbers that alerts saying written number is negative or positive. but I am getting negative always.

```js
function isPositive(num)
{
 if(num >= 0)
 {
  alert("Positive number");
 }
 else 
 {
  alert("Negative number");
 }
    document.getElementById("nummberOutput").innerHTML = num;
}
isPositive(0);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>HOMEWORK</title>
 <style type="text/css" src="style.css"></style>
</head>
<body>
 <input id="number" type="text">
 <button onclick="isPositive()">Negative or Positive</button>
 <div id="numberOutput"></div>
 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take a look at the data types as the data moves through the application, too. There's more than one issue in this homework assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing any number to `isPositive()` in `onclick` attribute, try below fix:

- Pass the value of `#number` input to the function
- You have an reference issue with the selector `nummberOutput`, it should be `numberOutput`

```js
function isPositive(num) {
 if(num >= 0) {
  alert("Positive number");
 } else {
  alert("Negative number");
 }
    document.getElementById("numberOutput").innerHTML = num;
}
```

```html
<input id="number" type="text">
<button onclick="isPositive(document.getElementById('number').value)">Negative or Positive</button>
<div id="numberOutput"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your onclick attribute of the button, you should put something like

```
isPositive(document.getElementById('number').value)
```

Else it takes nothing for argument so it is undefined. And as undefined is not comparable to 0, it goes to the "else" and says it's negative.